# How do I use a button to open a website from the browser on an Android widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-internet

So I have been trying for hours to get this to work and I can't for the life of me figure it out. I have tried many different ideas I've found just googling it, but without any luck. I am trying to create an android widget that you can click on an image and it uses the default browser to open up a website. I am able to get the image and widget working correctly, but when I try to implement the code for the button to open a website, it kills the widget and says "Problem loading gadget" on the phone. I'm fairly new to making widgets/apps so any advice is appreciated.
How can I make the widget work?

Here is my code:

**Main.xml**

```
$<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_frame_portrait"
>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/xmas"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"

        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:background="@drawable/feep"
        android:layout_width="225dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="openWebUrl"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My only activity called bGiving.Java:

```
$package chris.days.to;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class bGiving extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener  {

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                         int[] appWidgetIds) {

    }

    public void openWebURL(View v) {
        String url = "http://google.com";

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));

        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}

and my Android Manifest is:

    $<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="chris.days.to"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

        <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

            <receiver android:name=".DaysToXmas" android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                </intent-filter>
                <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                           android:resource="@xml/hello_widget_provider" />
            </receiver>

            <activity android:name=".bGiving"
                      android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

        </application>
    </manifest>
```

When I add in the code in the main.xml "android:onClick="openWebUrl" it kills the widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `PendingIntent` to your `Button`. This will cause the `Intent` to be executed when the `Button` is pressed.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(data);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Why do you have to have a remoteView object in it? What does that do?

Comment: Where should this be set - in the Service or in the AppWidgetProvider?  And in what method?